# How can I add a constant to an API link in PHP to retrieve specific user data?

Tags: php, api

So I am working in php and I am not very savvy in it....

I have a link to an api point but need to grab a constent and apply to the end of the link to make it one to pull data for a user.

Do I just `CURLOPT_URL => "link"` `echo $constent`?,

I have api system I am just trying to display data from api.

Comment: Is the API URL like `https://api.com/user/{userId}` or like `https://api.com/user?userId={userId}`?

Comment: https://api.com/user/{userId} thats what it would be so is that how you do it? you put the constent in brackets at end of the link?

Answer (score 1):

The PHP string concatenation operator is `.`, so you can just do something like this if you have a variable:

```php
$user = 'foo';
$url = 'https://api.com/user/' . $user;
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

Or this if you have a constant:

```php
define('USER', 'foo');
$url = 'https://api.com/user/' . USER;
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

Or better, use the optional init parameter and generate the URL inline:

```php
define('USER', 'foo');
$curl = curl_init('https://api.com/user/' . USER);
```

Also, if your userid has any wonky characters in it, you'll want to encode it:

```php
define('USER', 'foo?bar');
$curl = curl_init('https://api.com/user/' . urlencode(USER));
```

Comment: And if the USER is located on another php file. I know with html you would do <script> link to file then end. How does php bring in a file with the user defined? Then printing it? I tried echo out side the php but page is blank.

Comment: See [include/require](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).